# Solr : Stemming words Using Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, stemming

I am learning solr and want to use solr for stemming words.I'll be passing the word to the solr and it should send the stemmed word back.I know how to configure solr core for different stemming patterns and also i am able to view their stemmed words in the analyzer (solr admin ui) but i am not sure how to achieve this using java code.I am able to index and query using java api.

I am using solr-5.3.0.

Comment: here is an example http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti : I went through the example.But, i didn't get how to get the stemmed words back from solr.I am able to connect , add documents, delete documents, search etc, through JAVA API.I basically want to pass a word suppose hugging to solr through JAVA API and get back the word hug from it. How to do it ? I know i can see all the list of words specified by me in the field-type in schema.xml but i dont understand how to do it through java api.

Comment: ok got you now... I dont thik that is possible through java or solrJ...or may be possible ....but for that you need to what all apis been used by solr admin tool to get the data...

Comment: I searched a lot about it.But, i didn't get anything.Thanks anyways.

Comment: I have solr source code ...will check into it and let you know if I get anything into it...

Comment: does solr have hugging  indexed or you are passing it at runtime ?

Comment: passing at run time. Yeah , I solved it. Thanks.Able to do it using java.

Comment: you can post the solution to the question so that others may benefit from it.

Comment: @NikhilSahu : Use your browser's "developer tools" to see what is going on behind the
scenes when you use the admin UI analysis tab.

It is just an HTTP call that you can replicate from Java.

Comment: the URL should be something like:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/images/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldvalue=<stuff-you-want-analysing>&analysis.fieldname=<somefield>`

Comment: it returns a json , which can be parsed to get the stemmed word.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just stem the words I would recommend you not to use the whole Solr. Just use the code they use for stemming or something similar. E.g. you can use

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.PorterStemmer.stem(String)
```

Unfortunately `PorterStemmer` has package level access so I would just copy it from the sources or you can search the Internet for some other stemmer implementations. I hope that helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Btw, I have noticed that Lucene Porter Stemmer Solr uses is actually derived from here: http://www.tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/index.html. You can notice that from the comments on the top of the source.